# Why is $M_{k \times k}(S)$ a subring of $M_{k \times k}$(R) for all $k\geq1$ if $S$ is a subring of $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $S$ is a subring of $R$, then $M_{k \times k}(S)$ is a subring of $M_{k \times k}$(R) for all $k\geq1$

I know that if $S$ is a subring of $R$ then $(S,+)$ is a subgroup of $(R,+)$, and S has multiplicative closure.

And $M_{k \times k}(S)$ = $\{ {k\times k}$ matrices with cofficients in $S$}.

I have also found the subring test so I know that for $M_{k \times k}(S)$ to be a subring of $M_{k \times k}$(R) then we need:

- $M_{k \times k}(S)$ is nonempty
- additive closure and inverses in $M_{k \times k}(S)$
- multiplicative closure in $M_{k \times k}(S)$

I believe I just need to show these things, but I am not sure how to show these things using the information given.

Comment: Are you sure you wrote down everything? It looks incomplete.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: If you don't know where to start, edit in the definition of a subring first.

Comment: @divide1918 Done, thanks.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @shaun I have edited the title, thanks!

Comment: Did you mean 2x2 matrices or k x k matrices?

Comment: Also I'm not sure if it's typo, but you wrote that the matrices in $M_{k\times k}(S)$ have coefficients in R. In this case it's right since $S\subset R$, but I'm not sure if that's what you really intended

Comment: @Divide1918 I have corrected those errors, thanks for pointing them out

Answer (score 1):

$M_k (S)$ is a ring itself. Since $S \subset R$ you must have that a matrix with entries in $S$ is a matrix with entries in $R$. You don't need any kind of test, because you get that $M_k(S) \subset M_k (R)$ and $M_k(S)$ is a ring, so $M_k(S)$ is a subring of $M_k(R)$ by definition.

Comment: I feel like proving $M_k(S)$ is a ring is not only the meat of the whole proof, but also that, compared to it, everything seems trivial

Comment: So in other words what I'm saying is that imo you barely said anything in this answer

Answer (score 1):

I will show, as a demonstration, $M_k(S)$ have additive identity (I assume you're using the defition of ring with identity) and additive inverse.

Since S is a ring, there is an element $0$ such that for any element $s\in S, s+0=0+s=s$. Therefore, if we construct $O_k\in M_k(S)$ with each of its entry being $0\in S$, then for any $S_k\in M_k(S)$, we clearly have $S_k+O_k=O_k+S_k=S_k$. That is, $O_k$ is the additive identity of $M_k(S)$.

Similarly, for any $S'\in M_k(S)$, we may construct a matrix $T'\in M_k(S)$ from taking the additive inverse of each entry, which exists since they lie in $S$. Then clearly $T'$ is the additive inverse of $S'$ in $M_k(S)$.

Comment: I understand, thanks. Do I also need to show multiplicative closure in $M_{k \times k}(S)$?

Comment: Yes, of course. Try it yourself.